# Create a bash alias to compile any .java program in the current directory

Tags: java, bash, compilation, alias

I am attempting to create a bash alias that compiles all files with the `.java` extension and then runs all the files with the `.class` extension in the current working directory.

I currently have the alias

```
alias jcompile="cd $pwd; javac *.java; java *.class"
```

I would expect this to find any java programs and compile them, and then run them, but it throws this error.

```
error: file not found: *.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
Error: Could not find or load main class *.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *.class
```

Comment: What contains `$pwd`?

Comment: i was trying to get the working directory, i guess it was supposed to be `$PWD`

Comment: `cd $(pwd)` or better `cd "$PWD"`. But both are useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're defining `$pwd` specifically, it doesn't mean anything. `pwd` is a command that will tell you your current path, and `$PWD` is a variable that holds your current path. If you are defining a variable `pwd`, you might want to change it to something more distinctive.

If you want your function to run in a location that isn't your current directory, you could pass it as an argument:

```
jcompile() {
  cd "$1"
  javac *.java
  java *.class
}
```

and run it via

```
jcompile /my/path/to/directory
```

Comment: i was using pwd to get the working directory, not defining a new one

Comment: then just remove that part of the alias, and it should work. You don't need to `cd` to your current location, you're already there.